# iOS xcode for variable in iboutlet

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, interface-builder

Hey everyone so i have this code, and i want to optimize it

instead of doing this everywhere i want to add it in a for but i dont know how to add it

```
_p1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_p2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_p3.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_p4.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_p5.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_p6.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_p7.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_p8.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_p9.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

instead of this long code i want to add it in a for which will look like this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        _p[i].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `IBOutletCollection` is what you want. It is described in many places, e.g. http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Mats you should use `IBOutletCollection` so that you have an `NSArray` of views.

You can then also write your loop to be more obvious, for example with your attribute called `interactiveViews` and in a method where you supply `enabled` as a parameter so you can reuse it:

```
- (void)enableInteractiveViews:(BOOL)enabled
{
    for (UIView *view in interactiveViews) {
        view.userInteractionEnabled = enabled;
    }
}
```